# Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have two methods which are clashing

```
1. @RequestMapping(value = { "/{name}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    void foo1(@PathVariable("name") final String name) 

2. @RequestMapping(value = { "/{email}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    void getTemplateVersionsBySenderForClient(@PathVariable("email") final String email,
            @RequestParam(value = "timestamp", required = true) final long timestamp)
```

How do i avoid this?

Comment: as a user, how are you supposed to distinguish between these two mappings? you'd better provide semantically significant URIs (/name/{name} and /email/{email})

Answer (score -1):

You can change the URI templates to something else. You can also change the "email" URI template to use regular expression, so that the path that looks like an email address is processed by the second method. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html, under "URI Template Patterns with Regular Expressions":

```
@RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]+}-{version:\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d}{extension:\\.[a-z]+}")
public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {
  // ...
}
```